# Check if a method can be invoked with the array of parameters

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm [invoking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) a method using reflection but i want to check that the array of parameters i have are of the correct type before doing so. I've tried several methods like Type.IsAssignableFrom and other comparisons, but they still give false positives. For example when using an `int` as parameter to a function that accepts an `enum`.

The [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs,ec1a5b5efa8f60f3,references) seems to do exactly this check, is this exposed somewhere?

My current code looks like this:

```
private bool CheckTypeMatch(ParameterInfo[] methodParameters, Type[] callParameterTypes)
{
    if (methodParameters.Length < callParameterTypes.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < callParameterTypes.Length; index++)
    {
        Type type = methodParameters[index].ParameterType;

        if (callParameterTypes[index] != null && !type.IsAssignableFrom(callParameterTypes[index]) && !(type.IsEnum && System.Enum.GetUnderlyingType(type).IsAssignableFrom(callParameterTypes[index])))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I am worried there are more cases where the type of the parameter is actually compatible with the method but is being rejected by this function.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to mimic the entire applicability checking logic that the C# compiler uses, or just a subset of it?

Comment: Preferably every check. I actually modified my own code to see if its assignable or else an enum with an assignable underlying type. Not very clean in my opinion, and i fear there will be other cases too.

Comment: If you want to run the compiler at run-time, the usual way to approach that is to use `dynamic` types. You can catch exceptions if they occur, as a way of identifying invalid calls. It's not clear from your question exactly what kind of answer would be suitable, never mind best. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: I dont want to run a compiler at runtime at all. I have an array of objects, i'd like to know if i can invoke a method with them without causing an argument exception before actually invoking the method.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for the feedback, i have provided a code sample to better illustrate what i am trying to do.

Comment: I am doing something similiar for a mappingcreation. The code you provided here works 99% of the time. (Not sure about the enum part). If the methods are generic than thats a different story however.